# Why does this index make one query faster but another one slower

Tags: index, postgresql-performance, select

I am optimizing my database I found an index that makes one query go from 400ms to 2ms but it also makes another query go from 1000ms to 4000ms. It seems that the planner is choosing a suboptimal path but I don't understand why. So, if anyone could help me understand the why and perhaps even how to keep both queries optimized, that would be fantastic!

The query in question is this:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
  run.changeset,
  AVG(frame.cpuft),
  MIN(frame.cpuft),
  MAX(frame.cpuft)
FROM
  frame
  JOIN run ON run.id = frame.run_id
  JOIN tag ON run.id = tag.run_id AND frame.frame = tag.frame
WHERE
  run.build_target = 'build-target'
  AND run.branch = '/branch'
  AND tag.key = (select id from key where key = 'key')
GROUP BY
  run.changeset;
```

Which results in an EXPLAIN ANALYZE of

```
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=304796.78..305102.57 rows=272 width=20) (actual time=946.952..972.960 rows=29 loops=1)
   Group Key: run.changeset
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on key  (cost=0.00..1.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (key = 'key'::text)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 24
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=304795.46..305084.26 rows=1360 width=44) (actual time=946.795..972.920 rows=67 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 5
         Params Evaluated: $0
         Workers Launched: 5
         ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=303795.39..303920.41 rows=272 width=44) (actual time=858.558..885.578 rows=11 loops=6)
               Group Key: run.changeset
               ->  Sort  (cost=303795.39..303819.85 rows=9784 width=8) (actual time=857.275..866.671 rows=135224 loops=6)
                     Sort Key: run.changeset
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2424kB
                     Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2664kB
                     Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2344kB
                     Worker 2:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2488kB
                     Worker 3:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2224kB
                     Worker 4:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2168kB
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=39.98..303146.89 rows=9784 width=8) (actual time=85.321..832.638 rows=135224 loops=6)
                           Join Filter: (run.id = frame.run_id)
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=39.41..155105.61 rows=97800 width=16) (actual time=82.748..499.280 rows=135224 loops=6)
                                 Hash Cond: (tag.run_id = run.id)
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tag  (cost=0.00..154132.68 rows=354492 width=8) (actual time=7.202..385.794 rows=1370678 loops=6)
                                       Filter: (key = $0)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 1878835
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=34.84..34.84 rows=365 width=8) (actual time=0.676..0.677 rows=363 loops=6)
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 23kB
                                       ->  Seq Scan on run  (cost=0.00..34.84 rows=365 width=8) (actual time=0.456..0.632 rows=363 loops=6)
                                             Filter: ((build_target = 'build-target'::text) AND (branch = '/branch'::text))
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 960
                           ->  Index Scan using frame_run_id_frame_index on frame  (cost=0.57..1.50 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=811345)
                                 Index Cond: ((run_id = tag.run_id) AND (frame = tag.frame))
 Planning Time: 1.321 ms
 Execution Time: 974.050 ms
```

All fine and dandy, the **frame_run_id_frame_index** optimized this query by a lot 
Now, I added the following index to make a different query which only selects data from *run* and *tag* tables go a lot faster.

`CREATE INDEX tag_run_id_key ON tag (run_id, key);`

However, it makes the first query go a lot slower, here's the updated EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=692112.09..692417.89 rows=272 width=20) (actual time=4289.328..4317.578 rows=29 loops=1)
   Group Key: run.changeset
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on key  (cost=0.00..1.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (key = 'key'::text)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 24
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=692110.78..692399.57 rows=1360 width=44) (actual time=4288.049..4317.530 rows=67 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 5
         Params Evaluated: $0
         Workers Launched: 5
         ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=691110.70..691235.72 rows=272 width=44) (actual time=4219.868..4246.218 rows=11 loops=6)
               Group Key: run.changeset
               ->  Sort  (cost=691110.70..691135.16 rows=9784 width=8) (actual time=4218.829..4228.142 rows=135224 loops=6)
                     Sort Key: run.changeset
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2464kB
                     Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2192kB
                     Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2384kB
                     Worker 2:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2416kB
                     Worker 3:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2152kB
                     Worker 4:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2720kB
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=39.98..690462.21 rows=9784 width=8) (actual time=362.713..4193.869 rows=135224 loops=6)
                           Hash Cond: (frame.run_id = run.id)
                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..689846.15 rows=218973 width=12) (actual time=10.990..4074.797 rows=1370678 loops=6)
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tag  (cost=0.00..154132.68 rows=354492 width=8) (actual time=7.610..385.505 rows=1370678 loops=6)
                                       Filter: (key = $0)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 1878835
                                 ->  Index Scan using frame_run_id_frame_index on frame  (cost=0.57..1.50 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=8224066)
                                       Index Cond: ((run_id = tag.run_id) AND (frame = tag.frame))
                           ->  Hash  (cost=34.84..34.84 rows=365 width=8) (actual time=0.740..0.740 rows=363 loops=6)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 23kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on run  (cost=0.00..34.84 rows=365 width=8) (actual time=0.512..0.701 rows=363 loops=6)
                                       Filter: ((build_target = 'build-target'::text) AND (branch = '/branch'::text))
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 960
 Planning Time: 0.954 ms
 Execution Time: 4318.716 ms
```

The big difference seems to be that the Nested Loop and Hash Join are done in different orders but I don't know what that means nor how I could fix it.
Any ideas on what could be causing this, how I can troubleshoot this further or any documentation that I can read?